# How to handle error in node/express and nextjs when jwt expires?

Tags: typescript, next.js, jwt

My nextjs application stopped after I received the error "Server Error. AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401". In my application's vscode terminal in next I am receiving path: '/api/recover-user', data: { error: 'jwt expired', success: false } and page: '/dashboard', that is, on the dashboard page When the request is made to api/recover-user I receive the error "Server Error. AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401" caused by the expired jwt.

The error data: { error: 'jwt expired', success: false } comes from my backend through the code:

```
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, async (err, decoded) => {
        if (err)
          return res.status(401).json({
            error: err.message,
            success: false,
          });
}
```

recoverUserInformation and AuthProvider are the frontend codes in next

```
export const recoverUserInformation = async (
  token: string
): Promise<IRecoverData> => {
  try {
    const apiClient = getAPIClient();
    const { data } = await apiClient.get('/recover-user', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
    return data.user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: IAuthProvider) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const isAuthenticated = !!user;

  useEffect(() => {
    const { nextAuthToken: token } = parseCookies();
    if (token) {
      recoverUserInformation(token)
        .then((userData) => {
          setUser(userData);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error recovering user information:', error);
          signOut();
        });
    }
  }, []);
  const signOut = () => {
    destroyCookie(undefined, 'nextAuthToken', { path: '/login' });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isAuthenticated, signIn, signOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to handle this error so thaty the application's frontend works again?